# Inline DisplayFormat of a memo in fastreport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a somewhat complex operation in a memo field in a fastreport in a Report Summary band:

```
[IIF(<fdsDataSet."Data1"> - <fdsDataSet."Data2"> >= 0, SUM(<fdsDataSet."Data1">-<fdsDataSet."Data2">) , '')]
```

I get a SUM, and it is working.

However, I need to format the number so it looks like 99.990,50

I tried this inline formatting, but I am getting an error with this code:

```
[IIF(<fdsDataSet."Data1"> - <fdsDataSet."Data2"> >= 0, FloatToStr(SUM(<fdsDataSet."Data1">-<fdsDataSet."Data2">) ) #n%2.2n , '')]
```

This is the error I get:

> Memo61: Error in expression 'IIF( -  >= 0,
>   FloatToStr(SUM(-) ) #n%2.2n ,
>   '')': ')' expected

Please, help! Thank you!

Comment: It is useful if you share the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `)` after `#n%2.2n`

```
[IIF(<fdsDataSet."Data1"> - <fdsDataSet."Data2"> >= 0, FloatToStr(SUM(<fdsDataSet."Data1">-<fdsDataSet."Data2">)  #n%2.2n ) , '')]
```

Also please look at  the syntax of `FloatToStr`, in your case it is:

```
FloatToStr(SUM(<fdsDataSet."Data1">-<fdsDataSet."Data2">)  #n%2.2n)
```

Are you sure that this is the proper syntax?

try to use

```
Format('#n%2.2n', FloatToStr(SUM(<fdsDataSet."Data1">-<fdsDataSet."Data2">)))
```

Comment: I did, but it returns the same error. Besides, there is no need for the extra bracket there. As I see it, there should be like this: 
[ IIF ( ... ) ]

Comment: Please, see. I updated the answer.  add `)` after `#n%2.2n`

Comment: I did it, but to no avail. Still the same error... Thank you though

Comment: It is because yout FloatToStr is not correct. See update

Comment: That is right because your cann't pass 2 params into FloatToStr. Use function ` Format(Fmt: String; Args: array): String`. See update

Comment: Hello, well, thank you. I am sorry I didnt reply before. I was too busy. Yes, I solved the problem by removing floattostr... I only left normal SUM inside IIF and that is it... Thank you very much for trying.